# if Button Exists then click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, web

I searched and searched questions similar to my question but were either in other languages ​​or tested and did not answer so I had to ask a question.
I wrote a plugin for Chrome Now it's a problem for the site I wrote the plugin
Recently, 2 buttons have been added to the site

I want to write a function that constantly checks if there is a button (refresh_button) to do it click on it.
And then a new page opens with a button named (play_button) inside it
Check if it does exist. Click on it

here's my function for this work but its not working

```
var t_refreshBtn=document.getElementsByClassName("refresh_button")[0];
var t_playBtn=document.getElementsByClassName("play_button")[0];
var interval = 10;
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('#refresh_button').length > 0){
    t_refreshBtn.click();
        }
     window.clearInterval(timer);

}, interval);
```

Comment: Please show error text.

Comment: You clear the interval immediately. Try `var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if($('#refresh_button').length > 0){
    t_refreshBtn.click();      window.clearInterval(timer);
   }

}, interval);`

Comment: And Interval for SetInterval in milliseconds, so 10 ms it is almost instaclick.

Comment: Your adding elements to the variables via classname, but trying to access it later via id? plus, your using jQuery as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const button = $('#refresh_button');

button.length > 0 ? button.click() : alert('No button for you') // BOOM 1 liner
```

Answer (score 1):

I see you'r using JQuery. you can try.

```
 if($('#refresh_button').length > 0){
    $('#refresh_button').trigger("click");
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check only if your `t_refreshBtn` is exists then bind `click()` event else do whatever you want:

```js
var t_refreshBtn=document.getElementsByClassName("refresh_button")[0];
var t_playBtn=document.getElementsByClassName("play_button")[0];
var interval = 1000;
var timer = window.setInterval(function(){
    if(t_refreshBtn){
       t_refreshBtn.click();
    }else{
       console.log("Button not found");
    }
    window.clearInterval(timer);

}, interval);
```

Comment: its just refresh and refresh again even without any button in page : (

Comment: i changed the interval to 10,000 and its worked like a charm great thanks 
but an other question how can i add to click on play button if exists too ??

Comment: you can does same thing on t_playBtn button too.

Comment: bro i set the interval to 10,000 but even if there's no refresh button but its refreshing the page